# Change toolbar like gmail Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar

Gmail shows us an feature that it changes the toolbar color and button , and also highlight the recycleView when we click on the circle. Is there anyway I can implement this feature?

To make thing clear, I have added 2 images to show what I meant(notice on the 3rd row).

Before : 
[image]

After : 
[image]

Comment: but i thought google suggest people using toolbar instead of action  bar now?

Comment: API 21 introduced to material design, you need to use Tollbar and experiment with Dark and Light themes.

Comment: You can googled that question and read articles about toolbar. (Hint: you can use toolbar directly or via using helper library aka AppCompat)

Comment: I do know how to use toolbar, it just seen to be odd for me to use action bar again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use

```
ActionMode.Callback {
    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contextual_menu, menu);
    return true;
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        mode.setTitle("CheckBox is Checked");
        return false;
}
```

with AppCompat for toolbar (android.support.v7.widget.toolbar)
and then `Activity.startActionMode(new ActionBarCallBack());`

Comment: Is there any way i can put the actionmode call back in adapter?

Comment: do you want to mark items as checked? you can use custom adapter that has method setChecked(int position) and proxy callback to adapter.